# What's the explanation behind grown-up Cal in the Season 3 finale of Manifest?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, manifest

In the final scene of season 3 of *Manifest*, when

> Grace is lying on the floor dying

you can see a grown-up Cal hanging over her.

The premise of the show is that the world got older and the passengers of Flight 828 stayed the same. But now the world has stayed the same, and Cal has gotten older, which does not really make sense to me. **Is there a logical explanation for this?**

Comment: Likely to be explained in the never going to happen S4.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I read some rumours that a season 4 might be happening, but I highly doubt it.